# Clickable Table of Contents without using Section/Subsection/etc. Tag

Tags: table-of-contents, links

Is there a way of creating a clickable Table of Contents without using any of the 'Section' tags?
This code should be multiple times (creating the elements for the Table of Contents):

```
\begin{center}
   \phantom{.}
   \vfill
   \textsc{\textbf{\huge Foo}}
   \vfill
\end{center}
```

I know that it might be easier to use \section for this but I want the elements to look like this.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the '\section' and so on?

Comment: Would be to much work to change all the \section tag so it would similar to the code provided. Or what do you think?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "The Table of Contents should link to this: <code>" . Do you have a clearer example to show what is the output that you want?

Comment: When I click on one of the elements of the ToC instead of referencing to /section it should refer to something like the code provided. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: But what *are* the elements of the TOC? You have none. Look up \addcontentsline in the LaTeX manual (I think) and \phantomsection in the hyperref manual.

Comment: I think it is MUCH easier to request sections to be centered and fill a page than to reprogram them from the beginning -- which is likely to include a bunch of errors.

Comment: So the code I provided should be repeated multiple times. Each time it is repeated it should add a new element in the ToC. The elements shown in the ToC should be the Foo or whatever you want to put instead of it. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau I get that it is easier to use sections, but I don't want to put in the effort of changing the \section to have it look the same way as the provided code.

Comment: I'm saying that effort is small compared with making your own code that does the things \section does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the packages mentioned in the FAQ answer https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-secthead. But it is usually easy to redefine sectioning with the built-in `\@startsection`.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection
  {section}{1}{0pt}{-12pt plus -1fill}{12pt plus 1fill}%
  {\huge\scshape\bfseries\centering}}
\makeatother
```

I forget what documentation explains `\@startsection` -- clsguide didn't have it, but you could find it in ltsect.dtx.

Edit, based on comments:  The first `\vfill` should not be discarded at a page break, and the regular `\section` command should be retained for other types of sections, like the ToC heading. So using a random name instead of "section"

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\blob{\@startsection
  {section}{1}{0pt}{-1pt}{12pt plus 1fill}%
  {\huge\scshape\bfseries\centering \mbox{}\\*[\fill]}}
\makeatother
```

I retained the name "section" so the ToC entries are formatted the same was as regular `\section` entries.

[I am still uneasy about the huge flexibility of `\vfill` and wonder if the `\part` command is closer to what appearance is desired.]

If `\section` or some other command using `\@startsection` is out of the question, then make sure your code contains `\phantomsection` followed by `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{<the title>}`. In the original question, it would be

```
\begin{center}
  \phantom{.}
  \vfill
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Foo}%
  \textsc{\textbf{\huge Foo}}
  \vfill
\end{center}
```

You will have to use a font family that provides bold small-caps.

Comment: That seems to have worked, but now it also does the centring for the title of the contents page if I use \tableofcontents. Which I don't want.

Comment: Which "that"? Using \section as defined in the main code block does not center the ToC entry. I also wondered if the \vfill in the question indicated the title should be alone on a page.

Comment: Not the entry of the ToC but the automated title 'Contents' is handled as a \section. So it is also centred on the page.
Maybe I should also mention that I changed `{\huge\scscahpe\bfseries\centering}` to `{\huge\vfill\scscahpe\bfseries\centering}`.

Comment: Both \vfill were in my def (one is negated), but I neglected to have something to prevent it being discarded at the top of a page. Sorry. If it isn't the same sort of section as "Contents", then you could choose a different name. Maybe \part in the report class does what you want. If you don't use `\@startsection` (or a package) then be sure to use `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: I'm happy with the way the section looks, it just that the title of the table of contents, which is automatically added, gets the same kind of formating as the sections. I don't see how `\phantomsection` or `\addcontentsline` would help me.

Comment: You could temporarily disable \centering for the TOC using `{\let\centering\relax\tableofcontents}`